# Proof: If $(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)^°\neq\emptyset$ there exists $i^*\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(A_{i^*})^°\neq\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, baire-category

I am preparing for my upcoming exam by doing some exercises and need help for the following task:

> Let $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ be a sequence of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$ with the property that $(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)^°\neq\emptyset$. With help of the nested intervals theorem: Prove there exists a $i^*\in\mathbb{N}$ such that ($A_{i^*})°\neq\emptyset$

> Hint: Assume all $A_{i^*}°$ to be empty. Construct a descending sequence $B_1, B_2,...$ of  closed balls contained in $(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)°$ with the property $A_i\cap B_i$$\neq \emptyset$

Note: M° is the set of inner points of M.

First the nested intervals theorem:
Let $M_1,M_2,...$ be a sequence of bounded, closed, nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R^n}$  with the following properties:

- diam($M_i$):=$\displaystyle\sup_{\mathbf{x,y}\in M_i}|\mathbf{x-y}|\to 0 $ for $i \to \infty$
- $M_1\supseteq M_2\supseteq...$

Then there exists exactly one point $\mathbf{x}$ with $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}M_i$={$\mathbf{x}$}

Well to be honest, I am pretty overwhelmed by this task. Here are a few of my thoughts:

Well we at first have to assume $A_{i^*}°$ to be empty right. But is this how we should start? Or should I take the complement $(A_{i^*}°)^c$ which is nonempty. But I don't know how this should help me. I thought we can prove it like [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/336_14/papers/alana.pdf) on page 4. But I guess we can't prove this analogously.

Secondly I am not sure how to construct this descending sequence of closed balls with the menntioned properties above. But I guess this will be used for the nested intervals theorem. We will have $B_1\supseteq B_2 \supseteq B_3 \supseteq...$. But how will we then prove that $diam(B_i)\to 0$ for $i\to\infty$. And what use will the point {$\mathbf{x}$}$=\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}B_i$ have.

Or maybe I should prove the contraposition?

Is there anyone who could help me out? I am pretty lost right now and would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Baire's theorem directly? I suppose not, but you have tagged it

Comment: The strategy is: Show that the countable union of closed hollow sets is again hollow --> if a countable union of closed sets is not hollow, then there must exist at least one non-hollow set in that union (btw: closed and hollow is often said to be "nowhere dense")

Comment: So familiarity with Baire's proof of the countable union of hollow sets is again hollow (or the *equivalent statement* (which is imo easier to think about) that **the countable intersection of open dense sets is again dense**) gives you the solution

Comment: @FShrike No we are not allowed to use Baire's theorem directly. The thing is, that my teacher marked this task, that I have to prove, as "Baire's theorem".

Comment: Well, I’m saying that it’s conceptually easier to prove the dual statement that the countable intersection of open dense sets is dense and the complement of a union is the intersection of complements. Note that $(A_i)^c$ is open and dense. The proof that I know uses this “nested intervals theorem” (generally known as the Cantor intersection theorem for metric spaces)

Comment: @FShrike If you have a link for this proof, could you post it here please? Also...is it correct that "closed and hollow" is the contrary of "open and dense". And that the term dense means that the set has inner points?

Comment: No, not at all. You should have come across the word “dense” before Baire Category! Strange of your teachers not to do so... anyway, $A$ is dense means: $\overline{A}$ is the whole space, or equivalently, every open set intersects $A$. $A$ is a dense set iff. $A^c$ is hollow (=empty interior, no ”inner points”), this is a good (but straightforward! Don’t overthink it or get lost in words) exercise to verify.

Comment: @FShrike Yeah no we just learned things like  $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ but never did anything beyond that...anyway, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If you get very stuck, I will give a reference text to you or a full answer if needs be. It would be good if the question were fleshed out a bit more with your ideas (after you've thought on what I've said) as then it would be appropriate to answer. The core idea is this: Suppose the intersection of the open dense sets is not dense. Then there must exist a point and an open neighbourhood of this point which is not covered by the intersection; however, it is covered by each and every one of the open dense sets involved in the intersection: make a sequence for your "intervals"

Comment: It is good to verify first that the finite intersection of open dense sets is dense (begin with the intersection of a pair, then it is easy induction). Openness is important: $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ are both dense, but their intersection is empty which is obviously non-dense. Furthermore, dense sets can be hollow! E.g. $\Bbb Q$ is both dense and hollow, which can be weird to consider at first. So, the topological properties of openness/closedness are relevant

Comment: @FShrike So did I understand it right: I want to prove that the intersection of open and dense sets is dense too, right? Then we get that $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^c$ is open and dense too. We also prove that A^c is dense iff A is nonempty. Thus $(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)°=\emptyset$. But what then? Do we just say then that our lemma is true because it is the contraposition? I mean the contraposition would be that $(\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)°\neq\emptyset$ But what is the contrapositoon of $A_i$ being open and dense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136609/discussion-between-fshrike-and-analysis-mark).